# Is there a way to retrieve a list of all the addresses that have had activities from a extended public key?

Tags: address, public-key

Another way to put it. I want to get a list of all the addresses that have been used and are derived from the same extended public key. Is this doable? Thx.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, using blockchain.info you can do that:

https://blockchain.info/xpub/**Your Public Key Here**